# PHP curl extract download link

Tags: php, ajax, curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to extract a download link from this website using cURL.

> http://abelhas.pt/Asantino/TUTORIAIS/SONY+VEGAS/ZLICED+TRAILER/ZLICED+TRAILER/ZLICED+TRAILER+PRE-RENDERD+FX,36948354.mp4(video)

Opening the link gives u a download button, pressing it will then call a ajax script that returns some J SON data from following URL

> http://abelhas.pt/action/License/Download

This URL expects 2 parameters ( fileId(int) & __RequestVerificationToken(str)) as POST parameters and this header needs to be send aswell (X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest)

This is the script I'm using to login & fetch the **__RequestVerificationToken** && the **fileId** from the Item page

```
$options = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
                "Cookie:".$cookie.";\r\n" .  // check function.stream-context-create on php.net
                "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.102011-10-16 20:23:10\r\n"
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($options);

    $html = file_get_html($url,false,$context);
    $token = $html->find('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]',0)->value;
    $id = $html->find('a.fileCopyAction',0)->rel;
    return array(
        'id' => $id,
        'token' => $token
    );
```

Followed by this code that I use to extract the download link(this does not work)

```
$res = array();
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // do not return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => 'fileId='.$file_id.'&__RequestVerificationToken='.$token,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(
            'Accept:*/*',
            'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8',
            'Cache-Control: max-age=0',
            'Connection: keep-alive',
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Cookie: '.$cookie,
            'Host: abelhas.pt',
            'Origin: http://abelhas.pt',
            'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
        ),


    );
    $ch      = curl_init("http://abelhas.pt/action/License/Download");
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $res['content'] = $content;
    $res['url'] = $header['url'];
    return $res;
```

This returns J SON data but not what the website returns if u inspect it with chrome/firefox.

So the question remains : How to do this to get the same results as if visiting it urself using a browser?

Thanks in advance.